# C# Как при помощи DateTime узнать что прошла минута

Tags: c#, дата, datetime

В бд есть столбец Date в которое записывается время, при помощи

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()
```

Как при проверке, узнать что прошла минута?
Например 22:50:44
И при проверке в 22:51:58, код должен понять что прошла минута,или больше.

Comment: Уважаемый, буквально 3 вопроса назад по метке c# был аналогичный вопрос, по этому ваш можно смело закрывать дубликатом...

Comment: `DateTime` в строковом поле? "Вы погубите себя, мой юный друг!"